# Change directory of bash script by default

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script in my local bin folder so I can run it anywhere. In this script, I perform search and replace commands using sed.

When I run that script, I set $PWD as argument of the script so the sed commands work on the files in the folder where I started the script and not in the bin folder.

What do I have to adapt such that my script is always in the path I am calling from without using the workaround applying $PWD as argument?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need to, it'll do that by default. What you need to be careful about is to avoid paths relative to the script's location : those will need to be made absolute (or will require a `cd`) to work when you're calling the script from another location.

Comment: Just use dot `.` which is always the work dir and `$PWD`

Comment: @Aaron I actually did not know this! It works. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written by Aaron:

You don't need to, it'll do that by default. What you need to be careful about is to avoid paths relative to the script's location : those will need to be made absolute (or will require a cd) to work when you're calling the script from another location